# Press Menu & Sub-Menu before killing the process

Tags: batch-file

I have this bat file to just kill the file

```
start /d "path" file.exe
```

I need a code to press the Menu1 then SubMenu1 on that File then give 1 minute before I use the code above.

Can you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch files have no method of doing UI automation like you describe. I would recommend investigating VBScript (specifically the AppActivate and SendKeys functions) or another more robust language.